# PHP: Determine if any of a dozen variables have a particular value

Tags: php

Let's say I have a dozen variables, all having yes/no values. Is there any better way other than...

```
if ($q1=='yes' || $q2=='yes' || $q3=='yes'...
```

... to find out whether at least one of those values was equal to *yes*? Here is a `var_dump` of the array. I am only concerned with the `qX` values

```
array(16) {
  ["q1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q1"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q2"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q3"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q3"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q4"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q4"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q5"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q5"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q6"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q6"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q7"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q7"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q8"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q8"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q9"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "q9"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q10"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "q10"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q11"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "q11"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["q12"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "q12"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "no"
    }
  }
  ["fitness_test_pst"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["text"]=>
      string(22) "1 day PST (Bleep Test)"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "fitness_test_pst"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  ["pst_date"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "pst_date"
      ["value"]=>
      string(8) "2-5-2018"
    }
  }
  ["location"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["text"]=>
      string(8) "Here or there"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "location"
      ["value"]=>
      string(8) "Here or there"
    }
  }
  ["confirm"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(7) "confirm"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a dozen variables like that? Why aren't they in some array or object?

Comment: They are in an array, along with several dozen other key/values. I put them into variables so I can use them later on for various things.

Comment: @pee2pee that is not a reason to split an array. If you learn how to use arrays you will see how much easier things get. And this is one prime example of why not to split an array. Update the question with an var_dump of the array instead and we can help you far much more than this.

Comment: Added a cut down version of var_dump

Comment: @pee2pee answer posted.

Comment: @pee2pee Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal answer to this question would be something along the lines of:

```
if (in_array('yes', [$a, $b, $c, ...]))
```

But then the real question is why you have a dozen apparently related variables loosely floating around instead of having them in an array like that to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to find "q" arrays and the values "yes".

I use preg_grep on the keys of the array to find the subarrays with "q".
Then because the value is the key, I flip the array (swap places of keys and values) and use array_intersect_keys to extract the matching subarrays from $arr.

Then I use array_column to isolate the "value" column.

Then as the last step I see if there is any value "yes" in $values array.

It may look complex, but once you learn how to use array functions you will save so much time compared to assigning separate variables the way you do.

```
// Find all arrays with "q"
$q = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(preg_grep("/q\d+/", array_keys($arr))));

// From "q" array get all values
$values = array_column($q, 'value');

// See if any has 'yes'
If(in_array("yes", $values)) echo "at least one yes";
```